# Data not loading from MySql into textboxes on button click

Tags: php, mysql, forms, textbox

i have a little problem here. What i am trying to achieve is User types in unique id into textbox then presses load button, script is looking for this parameter in MySql database. When found match data should be loaded into textbox below.

UPDATED VERSION

```
<?php

mysql_connect ("localhost", "root","84946dff6e1")  or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("employees");


if(isset($_POST["loadbtn"]))
{
    $load = $_POST["loadbtn"];

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM titles WHERE emp_no = '$load' ");
    $details = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

    $savedTitle = $details["title"];     
}
?>
<form method="post" action="changeTitleView.php">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" align="center">
<tr>
<td width="150">Employee number</td>
<td><input type="text" name="load" /></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="loadbtn" value="Load" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<br />
<br />
<form method="get" action="changeTitleView.php">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" align="center">
<td width="150">Employee Title</td>
<td><input name="salary" type="text" value="<?php echo $savedTitle; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<td width="150"> </td>
<td>
<input name="add" type="submit" id="add" value="Update">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

[image]

thank you for looking and help :)

Comment: Your text box name is "load" and the submit button is also named "load"

Comment: You are saving the title to $savedTitle but you are echoing $empTitle

Comment: I cannot see variable $empTitle declared anywhere... Maybe you want to change it to $savedTitle.

Comment: did that already, i have now "textbox -> <input type="text" name="load" />" ..... button ->"<input type="submit" name="loadbtn" value="Load" />"

Comment: You also show this code page is named "changetitleView.php" which is different from the form action attibute named "changeTitle.php"  they must match if you want to refresh the current page after hitting submit button.

Comment: Ok, so how can i later on point to the other file where the whole script is ?? One file holds form, other php script

Comment: Anyway i have done as you said, and move the php script to the other file, so now all code is in one file - however data is still not loaded moreover after hitting load button all textboxes clear

Comment: There are so many problems it is hard to know where to begin.

Comment: Ok let me edit original post with my current code, maybe it will make things easier.

Comment: You dont want the value of loadbtn, you want the value of load which is the name of the text box.

Comment: i can't really see where is that

Comment: So have you lost interest? 2 days without comment...

Comment: sorry i have been away for a longer time :) its all now solved anyway i have scraped my old code and start all over again and eventually i got it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);// show all errors when debugging

// don't use these database commands
//mysql_connect ("localhost", "root","84946dff6e1")  or die (mysql_error());
//mysql_select_db ("employees");

// do it this way and don't show us your database credentials.
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', "root", "84946dff6e1",  'employees');

//declare your variables so if POST isn't true you don't have errors later

$load = "some Id";
$savedTitle = "no value yet!"; // use something interesting when testing

//you want the value of the textbox which name is load
if(isset($_POST["load"]))
{
    //never trust the user directly
     //$load = $_POST["load"]; 
     // do this
     $load = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST["load"]);

    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM titles WHERE emp_no = '$load' ");

    $details = $result->fetch_assoc();

    $savedTitle = $details["title"];     
    // show me error when testing to see if something is wrong with query
     echo $conn->error;
}
?>
<form method="post" action="changeTitleView.php">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" align="center">
<tr>
<td width="150">Employee number</td>
<td><input type="text" name="load" value="<?php echo $load; ?>" /></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="loadbtn" value="Load" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<br />
<br />
<form method="get" action="changeTitleView.php">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" align="center">
<td width="150">Employee Title</td>
<td><input name="salary" type="text" value="<?php echo $savedTitle; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<td width="150"> </td>
<td>
<input name="add" type="submit" id="add" value="Update">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

You will want to add another if branch to handle the second form which updates the title
And remember that form is GET instead of POST like the first form.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><input name="salary" type="text" value="<? echo $empTitle; ?>"></td>
```

try change that line to this:

```
<td><input name="salary" type="text" value="<?php echo $empTitle; ?>"></td>
```

Comment: didn't make any difference what so ever :(

Comment: are you sure localhost is running?

Comment: Yes it is running, Also what i have noticed is when clicking Load button, it redirects me to other site instead of staying on the same and loading data into textbox